# HashSet - How to search

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I have a HashSet of (a hashmap of (string and list of (hashmap of (two strings))))

```
HashSet<HashMap<String1,List<HashMap<String2,HashMap<String3,String4>>>>>
```

Now, I need to search with String inputs (StrA and StrB) and this should search the HashSet on

- StrA-->String1
- StrB-->String2

and it should return the hashMap of String 3 and String 4.

This is what I tried.

```
HashSet<HashMap<String,List<HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>>>> ObjList;

public void getElement(String strA, String strB) {
    if(ObjList.contains(strA) && ObjList.contains(strB))
        System.out.println("Yes");
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `Streams` would be :

```
HashSet<HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>>> fooSet = //;
String string1 = "string1";
String string2 = "string2";
HashMap<String, String> mapFound;


mapFound = fooSet.stream()                       // iterate over HashSet
       .filter(map -> map.containsKey(string1))  // keep maps that contains string1
       .findFirst()                              // take first map that match
       .orElseGet(HashMap::new)                  // take it really (or create new Map)
       .getOrDefault(string1, new ArrayList<>()) // take the List associated as value,or new List if not exists
       .stream()                                 // iterate over the list
       .filter(map -> map.containsKey(string2))  // keep maps that contains string2
       .findFirst()                              // take first map that match
       .orElseGet(HashMap::new)                  // take it really (or create new Map)
       .getOrDefault(string2, new HashMap<>());  // take HashMap associated as value, or new Map if not found
```

---

Solution with classic `for each` loop would be :

```
HashMap<String, String> mapFound;

for (HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>>> map : fooSet) {
    if (map.containsKey(string1)) {
        List<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> list = map.get(string1);
        for(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> map2 : list){
            if(map2.containsKey(string2)){
                mapFound = map2.get(string2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @azro. I used the foreach. Any comments on the performance of this search when I have like 1000s on outer HashMaps in my HashSet.

Comment: @ItsMeGokul okok, I've changed the first one to add security if not found

Answer (score 1):

There is no other choice than iterating both, the outer `Set` and the inner `List` (untested):

```
HashSet<HashMap<String1,List<HashMap<String2,HashMap<String3,String4>>>>> outer = //...

HashMap<String3,String4> result =
   outer.stream()
        .findFirst(map1-> map1.containsKey(string1))
        .get()
        .stream()
        .findFirst(map2-> map2.containsKey(string2))
        .get();
```